# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0 color

Tags: flutter, dart, indexing, range

It is a text editing app. I want to change my text color. I can't figure out what the error is.

```
      List<TextInfo> texts = [];
      int currentIndex = 0;
    
        changeTextColor(Color color) {
        setState(() {
          texts[currentIndex].color = color; //it works
        });
      }

      changeTextColor1(context) {
        Widget buildColorPicker() {
          return ColorPicker(
            pickerColor: texts[currentIndex].color, //there
            onColorChanged: (color) => setState(
              () => texts[currentIndex].color = color, //there     
            ),
          );
        }
```

I tried to assign the color of the current text to the variable.

[`Color pcolor = texts[currentIndex].color;`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCNOe.png)

Comment: show us your `TextInfo` class, please

Comment: its saying that texts[0] is null because your texts list is empty. That or the index is wrong. If your selected index is 1 but theres only 1 item in texts list, then you get an error too because it only has 1 index which is 0. The error is somewhere around that selectedIndex value that doesnt exist in the texts list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Precheck with texts.isNotEmpty() or List texts = [TextInfo()].

Gather and process overlapping locations in one place.

```
changeTextColor(Color color){
    if (texts.isEmpty()) return;
    texts[currentIndex].color = color;
}
....
....
setState(()=> changeTextColor(color));
```

Have a happy coding life. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list such as your "texts" variable, when you write code such as texts[0], you are actually trying to retrieve the first element in that list. But since the list is empty, that would result in a RangeError.

Since your texts list is empty and currentIndex is 0, your code texts[currentIndex] will generate a RangeError.

Comment: I need to initialize the List?